# Joomla Extension Manager - Sub menu missing

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

We are having an issue uninstalling a component in Joomla Extension Manager but just realised the sub menu [**Install | Component | Modules | Plugins | Languages | Templates**] is missing.

Any ideas as to why this maybe? Your responses are appreciated in advance.

Thanks IMVBank

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious thing to check would be your admin level. You have to be an Administrator or Super Administrator for the Extensions menu (where Install is located) to even show up. If you're a Manager or lower, you won't have access.

Comment: Actually just Administrator as I just discovered isn't enough to get to the Extension Manager. You have to be Super Administrator.